# Internal error on sending request(POST

Tags: javascript, apache

I have the following errors piling up daily in my Apache error log, every 5-10 minutes or so:

```
[Sun Jun 11 18:49:59] [lsapi:error] [pid 733425:tid 139] [client 111.1.1.1:57199] [host www.example.com] get_client_block(102400) failed, referer: http://www.example.com/
[Sun Jun 11 18:49:59] [lsapi:error] [pid 733425:tid 139] [client 111.1.1.1:57199] [host www.example.com] Internal error on sending request(POST /promote.php HTTP/1.1); uri(/ptp/promote.php) content-length(60): SendRequest: prepare(): user_get_body(bodyLocalBuf, 102400): read from client failed, referer: http://www.example.com/
```

I suspect it's from the following function I've been using:

```
function confirm() {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "promote.php?user=' . $link . '";
var params = "confirm_ref=' . urlencode(encrypt($reff,$key)) . '";
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

        }
            }
http.send(params);
}
```

The variables are php variables and are never blank.
But can't figure out where the problem might originate.
Any pointers? Thank you.

Comment: This is an internal _server_ error, so you don't look at the _client side_ code first. You start with the server side part, and apply the usual debugging measures there to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I am having a very similar error showing in my logs too.

Comment: Actually no, but I did managed to further reduce the occurrence of those errors by dropping mod_lsapi altogether and switching to php-fpm. What I have learned later that the root cause was actually a network issue caused by clients connecting through proxies, where the client would connect but then timeout while waiting for a reply.